# Android - how to get the last number user called?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making an app where the user can press a button and a phone intent will be launched to redial the last number. I already know how to make the phone call happen based on the URI data (phone num), but I'm unsure of how to retrieve the last phone number.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CallLog class to get at this information (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html).

You're interested in the getLastOutgoingCall method, which returns the last phone number called.

Answer (score 4):

The exact command you need is

```
String lastDialed = CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(getApplicationContext());
```

and of course don't forget to add the permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```